# Counting Random Instances of ID in an Organisation

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working in Crystal Reports XI, on generating a report for my organisation to show the number of times and employee works across multiple cost centres within the business.

We have a very dynamic workforce where e.g John Snow ID 5464H63, may work in multiple jobs across location, as could any other person in the organisation...so I canr just say count "5464H63".

I dont always know in which cost centre he is going to work or if he is going to work in more than one cost centre, so the formula needs to be dynamic, and not a Cross Tab.

I need to be able to show all the information in the details section of the Cost Centre --- and not Listing JOhn Snow and all the cost centres he works in, but listing him in each cost centre with a count of the other cost centres he works in.

I would really appreciate and be very greatful if anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: There is inadequate detail here to provide an answer. What does your data structure look like, key columns?

Comment: how did you group the report/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join: Cost_Center -- Emp -- Cost_Center_Alias
and add a join or filter condition to enforce Cost_center <> Cost_Center_Alias

You add the alias instance of Cost_Center by simply adding the same table a 2nd time to the report.

This would result in each Cost_Center & Emp combination joining to any cases where the emp also worked for another cost center.

Then, Group on Cost_Center 1 at level 1 and Employee at level 2.
Then, in the detail, show all the cases.
You can then count the number of times the employee worked for other cost centers and show that in GF2.

Use Group Report, Group Sort Expert to sort so that cost centers (Level 1) and Employees (Level 2) with the highest counts are at the top.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance - it helped me get to where I needed t go. Thansk for taking the time to help me out, much appreciated.